# Kentico Media Library Relative URL

Tags: kentico

We have a Kentico project where we're using Azure Blob Storage for our media storage. When selecting a media file in a page, it stores the URL like this: www.ourhost.net/blobcontainer/kenticosite/media/medialibrary/picture.jpg

We are also using ImageProcessor.org. This only works when the image is requested through the host itself, so we need the media library selector to store the absolute URL like this: /blobcontainer/kenticosite/media/medialibrary/picture.jpg

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance. Nicolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about `Media selection` form control, is that correct?

In this case the solution is for you to **remove** the protocol/domain from the absolute URL which is stored by the form control. You can do this by creating [Custom macro](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Registering+custom+macro+methods) since you are using Portal engine macros.

The purpose of the macro will simply be to take the absolute URL and make it a relative URL.

Instead of using this:

```
<img src="{% CurrentDocument["HeaderImage"] #%}" alt="{% CurrentDocument["Title"] #%}" />
```

You would call it like:

```
<img src="{% MyMacros.GetRelativeUrl(CurrentDocument["HeaderImage"]) #%}" alt="{% CurrentDocument["Title"] #%}" />
```

As you can see I'm using "MyMacros" namespace which is a best practise as it will enable you to keep all your macros organized. You can create custom namespaces as per [this article](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+macro+namespaces)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the `Media Selection` form control.

When I look in the custom page in the DB, at the media selection property, I see the absolute URL.

Comment: For the view itself we access the value with a macro `<img src="{% CurrentDocument["HeaderImage"] #%}" alt="{% CurrentDocument["Title"] #%}" />`. So it gets the absolute URL, which is saved like that, out of the DB.

Comment: I see, you are right - the media selection stores absolutely URL if CDN is used because the domain name is also important. I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: I've been looking into the custom transformation & macro's. Transformation will not be useful in our case right now, so a custom macro will indeed be the solution. Thank you very much for your help! Without this info I wouldn't have found it.

Comment: you're welcome. Hope you can do what you need! If you have any questions, feel free to comment :)